# Update an entire column with array elements in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table userx like this:

```
id----------text---------num          
1-----------foo-----------0  
2-----------bar-----------0  
3-----------widget--------0  
4-----------widget--------0  
5-----------widget--------0  
6-----------widget--------0  
7-----------widget--------0  
8-----------widget--------0
```

I have an array like this:

```
$numeros = array(30, 50, 60, 70, 90, 110, 130, 150);
```

So I want to make a query that gets every result from $numeros and update into my column (starting from id=1) "num" like this:

```
id----------text--------------num          
1-----------foo--------------30  
2-----------bar--------------50  
3-----------widget-----------60  
4-----------widget-----------70  
5-----------widget-----------90  
6-----------widget-----------110  
7-----------widget-----------130  
8-----------widget-----------150
```

Is possible make the update a single update (or multiple inside a loop) query for that?  how?

Comment: however, you COULD use a prepared statement inside a loop, and loop through the array binding a different value each iteration

Comment: This is one of the big problems with relational databases, it is way to hard to make vertical requests. If you wan to do this use MongoDB and javascript!

Comment: it's not so bad if you have an iterated column like he does with id. but yes, if a number got skipped in id, then he's screwed

Comment: yeah the conditions are very specific for it to work

Comment: If there a way to make this using a loop that sounds good to me guys. Please show me how.

Comment: @StenW: perhaps you would like to volunteer an answer demonstrating how simple this is using mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE userx SET num=? WHERE id=?";
for($j = 0, $j < sizeof(numeros); $j++)
{
    $index = $j+1;        
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $numeros[$j], $index);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

so while it's not technically one query, you're only writing it once

Comment: Im gonna take a look Jeff. Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure if $j+1 will work inside a bind_param call, but my point there is that the array starts at 0, and the id numbers start at 1, so you have to put $j+1 in there somehow to get the right association

Comment: yes, that not works but Im trying to resolve this using a for loop is the only way I think.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like updating every single element with one function calling another function through a for loop. IE

```
#CODE TO CONNECT TO Mysql database
#then call function to update these column elements
updateColumns();
function updateColumns(){
    $query = "SELECT column FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(!$result){
        echo "Error message you want.</br>";
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    else{
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count){
            # There are rows. now check if there is a match
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                #cycle through each row of the $result column
                foreach($row as $key => $value){
                    if($key){
                        updateThisColumnsValue($value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function updateThisColumnsValue($value){
    $query = "UPDATE table SET columnToCHange='newValue' WHERE referenceColumnName = '$value'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!result){
        error message
    }# that should be it. 
}
```

Also here is a link the the sql update function [w3school.sql](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)
I hope this helped.